# Index out of bounds in simple vector to matrix function

Tags: haskell

Getting started with Haskell here. It must be something very obvious, but I can't see it why the following simple code throws an "index out of bounds error".

```
module Main where

import           Data.Matrix
import qualified Data.Vector as V

vector2Diag:: Num a => V.Vector a -> Matrix a
vector2Diag vec = setDiag (identity (V.length vec)) 0 vec where
    setDiag m i v 
        | V.null v= m
        | otherwise = setDiag (setElem (V.head v) (i,i) m) (i+1) (V.tail v)

-- | The main entry point.
main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Welcome to FP Haskell Center"    
    print (identity (V.length (V.replicate 4 2)))
    print (vector2Diag (V.replicate 3 2))
```

This is error output:

./Data/Vector/Generic/Mutable.hs:596 (write): index out of bounds (-4,9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setElem` is not zero indexed, it starts with 1.

The error comes because you call `setElem 2 (0,0) m`.

If you change the `0` in

```
vector2Diag vec = setDiag (identity (V.length vec)) 0 vec where
```

to a `1`, it will do what you are trying to get it to do.